# Computing the Cohomology of Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, homology-cohomology

In Bredons "Topology and Geometry" [Chapter V, section 12] the following theorem is proven:

> If $G$ is a compact connected Lie group its $k$-th cohomology
>   $H^k(G,\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to the space of $k$-forms on the Lie
>   algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ that are invariant under the action induced by
>   $\mathrm{Ad} \colon G \to \mathrm{GL}(\mathfrak{g})$.

**My question:** Are there any interesting examples of Lie groups whose cohomology can be computed using this theorem *apart* from the $n$-torus $T^n= S^1 \times \ldots \times S^1$?

Thanks for your help!